# Object Moves Away From Original Position When Using Grab

Tags: objects, selection-tools

I haven't had this problem so far, but for this particular object, whenever I press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab the object to move it along some axis (by selecting x,y, or z) the object shifts from its original position before I select the axis and also doesn't clip back to the spot when I select the axis

[image: demo]

Comment: maybe because you've enabled the Snapping option (magnet icone?)

Comment: @moonboots Yup that was it. But I still don't understand why that was the problem

Comment: because it sticks to the face of the cup I guess?

Comment: @moonboots Ohhu, okay I get it now. Thank you :)